# Is there a disqus-like comment system that does not load google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, blog, comments

I am not using google analytics on my blog out of respect for user privacy (I don't care to make my blog a data-collection tool for Google).  I included Disqus (yes I know they track as well).

Politics & my reasons notwithstanding, **Is there a Disqus-like comment system that doesn't load google analytics?**

Comment: Doesn't load *Google* Analytics, or doesn't do any sort of stats collection at all? Given there's a [KB article](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-how-can-i-capture-disqus-commenting-activity-in-my-own-analytics-tool-) on *adding* GA to Disqus, your question doesn't seem to make sense. (For the record, this seems highly unlikely. Generally speaking the trade-off for services, especially if they're free, is that you're paying with user/behavioral data.)

Comment: @Su' load disqus on an otherwise empty page then check the scripts pane, find "google".  Disqus loads Google Analytics as well as Quantserve or something like that.

Comment: Okay, but is your problem with Google *only*? (Hence, the or in my question.) eg. If Disqus dropped GA but still had Quantserve, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Just my opinion, but most web users don't mind sharing the sort of data that GA collects. Users that DO care are generally web-savvy enough to install plugins/applications that block things like GA from loading in the first place, like the Ghostery plugin.

Also, given the popularity of GA the chances of a person ONLY encountering it on your site are slim, meaning that your decision NOT to use GA will do very little to keep data about them from being collected.

I believe it is fair to say that anyone using the internet expects SOME data to be collected on their use of certain websites.

Comment: "Politics & my reasons notwithstanding." I don't care to debate my reasoning, I use ghostery and am aware of the data-for-free-services trade off.  Respectfully: if you have an answer to the question please let me know, I've made clear I don't want to debate the politics of it.

Answer (score 2):

Livefyre is a commenting system like disqus that doesn't load GA.